# Get Index from ITEMIDLIST?

Tags: winapi, com

Given an `ITEMID_CHILD` (`ITEMIDLIST`) obtained from an `IEnumIDList::Next()` which is an enumeration of `IFolderView::Items()`, how do you convert the ITEMIDLIST to the index which would be needed in something like `IFolderView::SelectItem()`?

P.S. I know IFolderView::SelectAndPositionItems() exists, but this question is specific to obtaining the index (I couldn't find where an `::IndexOf()` exists)

TIA!!

Comment: use `IFolderView::Item` method if you want later select item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no *direct* way exposed by `IFolderView` to get the index of a given child `ITEMIDLIST`. You have to remember the index manually while enumerating the folder's items with `IEnumIDList`.  Or, you can loop through the items using [`IFolderView::Item()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifolderview-item) until you find an index that returns a matching `ITEMIDLIST`.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to use [`IShellFolderView::UpdateObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-ishellfolderview-updateobject), passing in the pidl as the first two arguments.  [`IShellFolderView::RefreshObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-ishellfolderview-refreshobject) also looked like an option, but for me it returns `E_NOTIMPL`.